# Why is my angular function works in Android and Windows but not in iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, angularjs

I have a tinder-like angular app [here](http://430designs.com/xperience/black-label-app/deck.php).

The After 4 right swipes, you're supposed to be taken to a new page. However, on any iPhone, iPad or Mac device it doesn't work. This works in Chrome and firefox both on desktop and mobile.

The error I'm receiving is `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Object.values(frequency)')`

It's pointing to controller.js on line 74. 
Here's my entire controller.js file:

```
angular.module('black-label', ['ngTouch', 'ngSwippy'])
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $timeout, $window) {
    $scope.cardsCollection = [{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_01.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_02.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_03.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_04.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_05.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_06.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_01.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_02.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_03.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_04.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_05.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_06.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_01.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_02.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_03.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_04.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_05.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_06.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_01.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_02.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_03.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_04.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_05.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_06.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_01.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_02.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_03.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_04.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_05.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_06.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_01.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_02.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_03.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_04.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_05.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_06.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_01.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_02.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_03.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_04.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_05.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_06.jpg',collection:'vineyard',}];
    // Do the shuffle
    var shuffleArray = function(array) {
        var m = array.length,
            t, i;
        // While there remain elements to shuffle
        while (m) {
            // Pick a remaining element
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
            // And swap it with the current element.
            t = array[m];
            array[m] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
        return array;
    };
    $scope.deck = shuffleArray($scope.cardsCollection);
    $scope.myCustomFunction = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.clickedTimes = $scope.clickedTimes + 1;
            $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Click on item' });
        });
    }; //end myCustomFunction
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.showinfo = false;
    $scope.clickedTimes = 0;
    $scope.actions = [];
    $scope.picks = [];
    var counterRight = 0;
    var counterLeft = 0;
    var newVar = $scope;
    $scope.swipeend = function() {
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Collection Empty' });
        $window.location.href = 'theme-default.php';
    }; //endswipeend
    $scope.swipeLeft = function(person) {
        //Essentially do nothing
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Left swipe' });
        $('.circle.x').addClass('dislike');
        $('.circle.x').removeClass('dislike');
        $(this).each(function() {
            return counterLeft++;
        });
    }; //end swipeLeft
    $scope.swipeRight = function(person) {
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Right swipe' });
        // Count the number of right swipes
        $(this).each(function() {
            return counterRight++;
        });
        $scope.picks.push(person.collection);
        // Checking the circles
        $('.circle').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
                $(this).addClass('checked');
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (counterRight === 4) {
            // Calculate and store the frequency of each swipe
            var frequency = $scope.picks.reduce(function(frequency, swipe) {
                var sofar = frequency[swipe];
                if (!sofar) {
                    frequency[swipe] = 1;
                } else {
                    frequency[swipe] = frequency[swipe] + 1;
                }
                return frequency;
            }, {});
            var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(frequency)); // most frequent
            // find key for the most frequent value
            var winner =Object.keys(frequency).find(function (element) { return frequency[element] == max; });
            $window.location.href = 'theme-' + winner + '.php';
        } //end 4 swipes
    }; //end swipeRight
})
.directive('ngSwippy', ['swipe', function(swipe) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            $(".fake-swipe").on("click", function(evt) {
                angular.element(this).addClass('happy');
                angular.element(this).removeClass('happy');
                var sign = $(this).hasClass("swippy-like")?1:-1;
                var card = $("div.content-wrapper.swipable-card:last", element/*"div.ng-swippy"*/);
                card.trigger("mousedown");
                card.animate({ left:sign*$("body").width() }, 350, function() {
                  card.trigger("mouseup");
                });
                setTimeout(function() {
                  card.trigger("mousemove");
                },300);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There's gotta be something I'm missing.  Please help!

Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

`Object.values()` is an experimental feature which is supported by Chrome and Firefox, but is not supported by Internet Explorer, Opera, or Safari.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility

That linked page will also direct you to some polyfill scripts that you can include to add the missing function in browsers that do not currently support it.

Comment: Is there any shim or polyfill you'd recommend? It seems that it should just work after adding one.

Comment: Yes any shim should just work, I don't think there's much to choose except if you use any shims try to pick a consistent set.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to implement it? I found this [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/Object.values).  Just not sure which file to include in my page

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Duncan's answer you can replace `Object.values()` with `Object.keys(frequency).map(k=>frequency[k])`. This maps every key in the keyset to its value. The output is an array of all values.

EDIT: OP used ES5 therefore

```
Object.keys(frequency).map(function(k){ return frequency[k]; });
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however, I'm getting an error in Safari in the map function. It's throwing a syntax error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'`.  Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for that. However, Safari is still giving me trouble. The error now is `undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Object.keys(frequency).find(function (element) { return frequency[element] == max; })')`. Chrome and FF are still good.

Comment: It looks like `element` isn't being passed in Safari, but is fine in Chrome. Thoughts?

Comment: It looks to me you're new to cross browser solutions. Please conduct further research.